# Keras JSON export: inbound_nodes

Tags: json, export, keras, keras-layer

I am trying to understand and how to interprate the JSON representation of a keras model. Each layer has it's inputs saved within the field `inbound_nodes`. What I don't understand are they arrays.

For example for 2 Inputs for a merge layer it looks like that:

```
inbound_nodes: [
  [
    ['average_pooling2d_1', 0, 0, {}],
    ['conv2d_3', 0, 0, {}],
  ]
]
```

Whats up with all the arrays? Why not save like that:

```
inbound_nodes: ['average_pooling2d_1', 'conv2d_3']
```

I guess the structure is because sometimes additional information must be saved somehow. What kind of information is that? E.g. when is the size of inbound_nodes > 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameters behind 'pooling2d' may be designed for future features.The size of inbound_nodes>1 when layers have other data stream.For more details,check the definition of Node and Layer [keras source code](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/engine/topology.py)

Answer (score 0):

So here is what I found out:

- The outer array is used if the Layer is reused.
- The inner array is used if the layer has multiple inputs.
- On position [0] is obviously the layer name.
- On position [1] is 1 if the "Layer" is the name is a Model e.g. ["Base Model", 1, ...] means the layer can be found in the Base Model config. It is 0 if the name corresponds to a Layer.
- On position [2] is the index of the output layer in case position [1] had a 1 and therefore represents a Model

still not sure about the dict